# How to create an index which includes a foreign key in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working with sequeilze, and have a model that has a foreign key (`belongsTo`).. For that the syntax looks something like this:

```
const modelOne = sequelizeClient.define(
    "model_one",
    {
       ...
    }
);

modelOne.belongsTo(modelTwo, {
    foreignKey: "modelTwoId",
    targetKey: "id",
    onDelete: "SET NULL"
});
```

After doing so, I am unable to add index that indclues the `modelTwoId` column in `modelOne`.

```
const modelOne = sequelizeClient.define(
    "model_one",
    {
       ...
    },
    indexes: [
            {
                unique: true,
                fields: ['col1', 'modelTwoId'],
            },
        ],
);
```

The error says: `error: column "modelTwoId" does not exist`

My guess is this is because sequeilze tries to create the index right after creating the model and before the foreign Key is added. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code modelTwoId must be the column name inside the modelTwo table if not change to the column name which is foreign key in modelTwo , it should fix the issue.